# DIY main battery swap on Volvo V70?

Tags: battery, volvo, replacements

The car is a **Volvo V70 2.0 D4 181 Momentum** from **2014**.

I bought it used in 2016, but in 2017 it started having problems with the automatic start-stop thing, and a year later it started saying "battery low" when parking. I have had it checked out by a garage, and they say that the generator and battery are in good condition.

Since then, the problems have been stable, but persistent. It has not had start-stop for a long time now. I recently read that start-stop requires a certain type of battery, and I do not know if that is what I have installed.

I'm thinking I should maybe buy a brand-new "proper" battery ... but I am unsure of the consequences of simply unplugging the battery in a modern car.

Do I need to have a garage do it? Can I do it myself, and if so, is there a certain protocol I should be following (beyond terminal dis/connect order), I mean to ensure the electronics and locks and such don't go wonky on me?

Comment: Have you checked out what a "proper" battery is for that car? Many sites on the internet have lists and many shops have catalogues showing the correct batteries.

Comment: To begin with I'm more concerned of dis- and reconnecting "any" battery.

Comment: Make sure you have any codes like radio the disconnect negative first and reconnect last.

Comment: "Any codes like radio" - yeah well, my "Media Infotainment" manual is 2.5x larger than the manual for the car itself, but doesn't (seem to) list any "codes" - I think, if these exist, they're only listed in service manuals?

Comment: Usually on a credit type card or metal tag for the keyring, may be written inside service book etc Seriously suggest you find it **before** disconnecting your battery. Otherwise your next post will be “radio does not work, how do I get the code”...

Comment: I have no such thing, but then again I bought the car used (from a dealer, but still). Come to think of it, I _did_ have such a tag for my previous vehicle.

Comment: @SolarMike I didn't think radio codes were much of an issue for modern cars nowadays. Aren't they generally electronically matched to the car in their firmware so they only lock out if they are moved to a different vehicle? I'm not familiar with American manufacturers but that is my (perhaps misguided) view of European makes.

Comment: Seconded! Never mind the radio -- I am really much more concerned that _the car itself_ needs some arcane incantation after a 'cold boot'.